# I receive an invalid hook call error in the search function

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, full-text-search

I was creating a function for my search bar but I receive this error:
[image]

Below is the function:

```
const HandleSearch = async (val) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await db.collection('accounts').orderBy('date').get();
        setAccounts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      };
  
      fetchData();
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setAccounts(
        accounts.filter(
          (account) =>
            account.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    }, [search, accounts]);
  }
```

Comment: can you share full component?

Answer (score 0):

you might be using the hooks in a wrong way. as per [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), hooks can only be called from React function components and from a custom Hooks. Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions, inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells hooks can only be called inside **function components**.

Try removing the `async` keyword preceding your component. This way React will understand it is a functional component and everything should work fine :)

At the moment it is not actually a component as components are supposed to return `JSX`. By preceding it with the `async` keyword it will implicitly return a `Promise`.

You can read more about `async` functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Promises are a pretty tricky concept and take time to fully understand.